# Next js app with SSR is not pre-rendering HTML, so web-scrapers cannot access the content

Tags: javascript, next.js, seo, server-side-rendering, vercel

I have a next.js app that uses server side rendering. When running the application both locally and in production (on vercel edge), the initial page response is returning what looks like a javascript bundle, and not the fully rendered HTML page. This means that all my SEO is made redundant, as the first response does not contain any of the `<meta/>` tags that I have defined. The page renders correctly in the browser, but I assume web scrapers only look at the initial response from the server.

Within the network tab, the first response with the "document" initiator contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style data-next-hide-fouc="true">
    body {
      display: none
    }
  </style><noscript data-next-hide-fouc="true">
    <style>
      body {
        display: block
      }
    </style>
  </noscript>
  <meta charSet="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta name="next-head-count" content="2" /><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
  <script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js?ts=1665897162450"></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js?ts=1665897162450" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1665897162450" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1665897162450" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1665897162450" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/development/_buildManifest.js?ts=1665897162450" defer=""></script>
  <script src="/_next/static/development/_ssgManifest.js?ts=1665897162450" defer=""></script><noscript
    id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="__next"></div>
  <script src="/_next/static/chunks/react-refresh.js?ts=1665897162450"></script>
  <script id="__NEXT_DATA__"
    type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"properties":[{"propertyId":"OsDbKrOmE4wRRUMzalxG","propertyAvg":2.888888888888889,"landlordAvg":2.777777777777778,"imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/student-property-1577144888882.appspot.com/o/property-images%2FOsDbKrOmE4wRRUMzalxG-ZkKIwuKwYua7ml8nEWOXYIV5tiK2-6214c8e0-4aec-11ed-b51b-75adb81e8353.png?alt=media\u0026token=2437767c-0877-470a-be6a-33f34c906a09","address":"312 Brooklands Road, Timperley, Manchester, UK"},{"propertyId":"NPwjd3YMPA8ddyzqBfmO","propertyAvg":3.888888888888889,"landlordAvg":4.111111111111112,"imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/student-property-1577144888882.appspot.com/o/property-images%2FNPwjd3YMPA8ddyzqBfmO-ZkKIwuKwYua7ml8nEWOXYIV5tiK2-b8072400-4c4a-11ed-9e75-f5ca509826c3.png?alt=media\u0026token=28ef7da1-711a-485a-8282-ffa1940f767d","address":"1 Wharncliffe Road, Broomhall, Sheffield, UK"},{"propertyId":"rxabfAynk5CfTIPwdRN3","propertyAvg":3.5,"landlordAvg":3,"imageUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/student-property-1577144888882.appspot.com/o/property-images%2FrxabfAynk5CfTIPwdRN3-ZkKIwuKwYua7ml8nEWOXYIV5tiK2-7a025420-4c24-11ed-bbda-e9dedbc50f17.jpg?alt=media\u0026token=1da2a00b-76d0-4371-a4e0-b0c77e995db2","address":"324 Grays Inn Road, London, UK"}]},"__N_SSP":true},"page":"/","query":{},"buildId":"development","isFallback":false,"gssp":true,"scriptLoader":[{"src":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAyIxfU1kI6ODZLE80-_XXyK7tdmY3Gk50\u0026libraries=places","strategy":"afterInteractive"}]}</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I was under the impression that next js would render full HTML pages on the server before sending them to the browser. I am not sure if there is a way to configure a "production" build option within the `next.config.js` file to make this happen, or whether this is a bug within next itself?

The following is my _app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../config/theme';
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, Container, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { MapsHomeWork } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { Auth, RouteProtect, Link } from '../components';
import { AuthContextProvider } from '../context/authContext';



export const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <Head>
        <meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB" />
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Student Property Reviews" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Box>
          <AppBar position='static'>
            <Container maxWidth="xl">
              <Toolbar disableGutters>
                <Link href='/'>
                  <MapsHomeWork sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'flex' }, mr: 1 }} />
                  <Typography
                    variant="h6"
                    sx={{
                      mr: 2,
                      display: { xs: 'none', sm: 'flex', md: 'flex' },
                      fontFamily: 'monospace',
                      fontWeight: 700,
                      letterSpacing: '.3rem',
                      color: 'inherit',
                      textDecoration: 'none',
                    }}
                    >
                    STUDENT PROPERTY REVIEW
                  </Typography>
                </Link>
                <Auth/>
              </Toolbar>
            </Container>
          </AppBar>
          <Container sx={{ marginBottom: '25px' }}>
            <RouteProtect>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </RouteProtect>
          </Container>
        </Box>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any help regarding this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does your `_app` looks like? You're most likely forcing client-side rendering somehow.

Comment: What would cause client-side rendering in _app? All that component does is return markup (using MUI components)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand. You must have some code that's causing it. Sharing the code for `_app` and the page you're rendering would help clarify it.

Comment: I will add it to the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this issue out. I had tried everything I thought I could, but when commenting out the `<AuthContextProvider/>` it seemed to work completely fine!

Within the auth context file, I was performing conditional rendering, depending on a `loading` state, which was causing SSR not to take place:

Previously:

```
const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user ? user : null);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const login = () => {
    return signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    setUser(null);
    await signOut(auth);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Now:

```
const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      setUser(user ? user : null);
    });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const login = () => {
    return signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
  };

  const logout = async () => {
    setUser(null);
    await signOut(auth);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many reasons why there is no rendering HTML the most common problem is there is something that is blocking the rendering, I give an example using Redux-Persist blocks totally the rendering so when you right-click on the page and click on `page source` you will see not HTML rendering, so you need to check what packages are blocking the rendering because not all NPM packages are very `friendly` with NextJS and make these behaviors.

Comment: These are my dependencies:
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.6",
    "@vercel/og": "^0.0.18",
    "firebase": "^9.10.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^3.4.2",
    "react-places-autocomplete": "^7.3.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"